# Getting trackpad to work with larswm in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, gnome, window-managers

I have probably a rather strange taste regarding window managers but the best one I have found so far is larswm. Although it is available in Debian Wheezy, making it useable involves a bit of system configuration. Most importantly trackpad support is handled by Gnome by default. What would be the recommended Debian way to enable trackpad support without Gnome?

Comment: Questions not related to programming are normally off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [SU].

Comment: Indeed. It has been answered on Super User http://superuser.com/questions/747527/configuring-larswm-to-use-touchpad-in-debian-wheezy .